# How to assign a name to JSON Array in Perl

Tags: json, perl

In my script to_json() converting loop_data in json format and assigning to $json.

```
my $json = to_json(\@loop_data);
print $json;
```

gives this output.

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Vivek",
        "Age": 20
    },
    {
        "Name": "Sonali",
        "Age": 19
    }
]
```

But instead of that i want print $json to give this output.

```
{"Friends" : [
    {
        "Name": "Vivek",
        "Age": 20
    },
    {
        "Name": "Sonali",
        "Age": 19
    }
]}
```

Where to add "Friends" and  {}.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could pass a reference to a hash with `Friends` as the key and a reference to your array as the value:

```
my $json = to_json({"Friends" => \@loop_data});
```